# Merge two dataframes by 2 columns - Deedle

Tags: c#, f#, deedle

I am trying to combine two deedle dataframes in a way similar to `merge` in pandas.
I will have one bigger frame where there is a `year` and `quarter` column with other data beside it, and then a smaller frame with a `year`, `quarter`, and `ad partner` column. I want to add the ad partner to every instance of the same year and quarter in the larger table.

There is some sample data at the link below:
https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-merge-dataframes-on-multiple-columns/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I now have this code, although it throws a `keyNotFound` exception if there is a key in `df1` that is not in `df2`, and does not return a table.

```
var df2ByYQ = df2.IndexRowsUsing(row => (row.GetAs<string>("Year".Trim()), row.GetAs<string>("Quarter".Trim())));
                
var bCol = df1.Rows.SelectOptional(kvp => df2ByYQ.Rows[(kvp.Value.Value.GetAs<string>("Year".Trim()), kvp.Value.Value.GetAs<string>("Quarter".Trim()))].TryGetAs<int>("b"));`
```

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by reindexing the two data frames so that they both have the same row index formed by a tuple consisting of the year and quarter. The easiest way to do this is to use the `Frame.indexRowsUsing` function. For example, given two frames with `a` column in one and `b` in the other:

```
let df1 =
  Frame.ofRecords [ 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q1"; a=1|} 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q2"; a=2|} ]

let df2 =
  Frame.ofRecords [ 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q1"; b=3|} 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q2"; b=4|} ]

let df1ByYQ = 
  df1 |> Frame.indexRowsUsing (fun row ->
    row.GetAs<int>("year"), row.GetAs<string>("quarter"))

let df2ByYQ = 
  df2 |> Frame.indexRowsUsing (fun row ->
    row.GetAs<int>("year"), row.GetAs<string>("quarter"))
```

Now you can use `join` to join the two frames - you just have to drop the columns that are shared in both of the frames (the operation does not allow overlapping columns):

```
let res = 
  df1ByYQ
  |> Frame.dropCol "year"
  |> Frame.dropCol "quarter"
  |> Frame.join JoinKind.Inner df2ByYQ
```

**EDIT:** In the scenario discussed in the comments, where `df1` has rows with multiple records per year/quarter and we want to add information from a unique row in another data frame, I would reindex the other data frame and then use the `map` operation to find the corresponding matching row in the other data frame (this will be quite fast, because lookup by index is done via a hashtable):

```
let df1 =
  Frame.ofRecords [ 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q1"; month="Jan"; a=1|} 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q1"; month="Feb"; a=2|} 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q2"; month="Jan"; a=3|} ]

let df2 =
  Frame.ofRecords [ 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q1"; b=3|} 
    {|year=1999; quarter="q2"; b=4|} ]

let df2ByYQ = 
  df2 |> Frame.indexRowsUsing (fun row ->
    row.GetAs<int>("year"), row.GetAs<string>("quarter"))

let bColumn = df1 |> Frame.mapRows (fun _ row ->
  df2ByYQ.Rows.[(row.GetAs "year", row.GetAs "quarter")].GetAs<int>("b") )

df1.AddColumn("b", bColumn)
```

Comment: Since I have rows with duplicate Year and quarter pairs, this will cause an error to be thrown since there cannot be two of the same indices.

Comment: @Tomas: Is it possible to get this to work using the [linked data](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-merge-dataframes-on-multiple-columns/), where the row index on `df1` isn't unique?

Comment: I think I would be able to answer if I had a specific example. Deedle is designed to work with unique index keys (unlike pandas) - but this partly means you sometimes need to more carefuly think about what you're trying to do. In this case, what does a duplicate row mean? Is there another thing that is a part of the key? Or does it mean you have to aggregate somehow? Or add value from the other frame to multiple rows of the first one?

Comment: There's a specific example in the [linked article](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-merge-dataframes-on-multiple-columns/). Basically, there's a row in `df1` for each month (i.e. three rows per quarter), but only one row per quarter in `df2`, so the problem is how to distribute each value of interest in `df2` over three separate rows in `df1`.

Comment: That makes sense! I edited my answer to post a possible solution for that case.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Great! is there any comparable function to Frame.MapRows in c#? Apologies for such newbie questions.

Comment: @Octo - You should be able to use `df.Rows.Select` to do this (following the LINQ naming in the C# API).

Comment: If there is an index in `df1` that is not in `df2`, I get a `keyNotFoundException`, is there anyway to ignore that and leave it as a missing value in the dataframe?

Comment: You can use `TryGetAs` to avoid the exception. To produce a series with missing data, you can either return `nan` if it is `float` or use the `SelectOptional` method which lets you return missing values.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I tried that in the edit to the question... likely implemented wrong